# Videoview gets stuck to blackscreen after restoring the app and plays the video after tapping on it

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to play two videos on two separate class. but Videoview gets stuck to blackscreen after restoring the app and plays the video after tapping on it.

i have tried with seekto and getposition but again received the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with Resuming video on resume?

Also

```
 @Override
 public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
   ArrayList<Object> sessionObject = new ArrayList<Object>();
   sessionObject.add(videoView.isPlaying());
   sessionObject.add(videoView.getCurrentPosition());
   sessionObject.add(videoView.getTag());
   return sessionObject;

 }
```

in Oncreate activity

```
    ArrayList<Object> initialPosition = new ArrayList<Object>();
    initialPosition.add(false);
    initialPosition.add(0);
    initialPosition.add(0);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayList<Object> currentPositionObject = (ArrayList<Object>) (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null ? getLastNonConfigurationInstance()
            : initialPosition);
    int currentPosition = Integer.parseInt(currentPositionObject.get(1)
            .toString());
    Boolean isPlaying = (Boolean) currentPositionObject.get(0);
```

Now you can seek your video to position you want to and can start it as follows.

```
    if (currentPosition != 0) {
        if (isPlaying) {

            videoView.start();
            videoView.seekTo(currentPosition);
        } else {

            videoView.seekTo(currentPosition);
            videoView.pause();
        }

    }
```

But still i have a problem with slight delay in orientation change.

You can save same elements in onPause method and add to bundle and on resume you can access the variables.